# Consolidating collections for a time-line type view

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Given an Meteor application that has multiple collections that need to be displayed together in a paged Facebook-style *timeline* view, I'm trying to decide on the best way to handle the publication of this data.

The requirements are as follows:

- Documents from different collections may be intermingled in the timeline view.
- The items should be sorted by a common field (the date, for example)
- There should be a paged-display limit with a "Load More..." button

To solve this problem I can see two possible approaches...

**Approach 1 - Overpublish**

Currently I have different collections for each type of data. This poses a problem for the efficient publishing of the information that I need. For example, if the current display limit is 100 then I need to publish 100 elements of *each* type of collection in order to be sure of displaying the latest 100 elements of the screen.

An example may make this clearer. Assume that the timeline display shows results from collections A, B, C and D. Potentially only one of those collections may have any data, so to be sure that I have enough data to display 100 items I'll need to fetch 100 items from each collection. In that case, however, I could be fetching and sending 400 items instead!

That's really not good at all.

Then, on the client side, I need to handling merging these collections such that I show the documents in order, which probably isn't a trivial task.

**Approach 2 - Combine all the collections**

The second approach that occurs to me it to have one enormous server side collection of generic objects. That is, instead of having collections A, B, C, and D, I'd instead have a master collection M with a `type` field that describes the type of data held by the document.

This would allow me to trivially retrieve the the latest documents without over publishing.

However I'm not yet sure what the full repercussions of this approach would be, especially with packages such as aldeed:autoform and aldeed:simple-schema.

My questions are:

- Does anyone here have and experience with these two approaches? If
  so, what other issues should I be aware of?
- Can anyone here suggest
  an alternative approach?

Comment: I usually go with a flavor of your approach 2. The first one is not workable at all. Paging is a major PITA there, for example

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the second approach, but do not put everything in there...

What I mean is that, for your timeline you need events, so you'd create an events collection that stores the basic information for each event (date, owner_id, etc) you'd also add the type of event and id to match another collection. So you'll keep your events just small enough to publish all is needed to then grab more details if there is a need.

You could then, either just publish your events, or publish the cursors of the other collections at the same time using the _id's to not over-publish. That event collection will become very handy for matching documents like if the user wants to see what in his timeline is related to user X or city Y...

I hope it helps you out.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I can't really do that in my case since I don't have any events of that type. I just need to sort the list by the last time each document was updated.

Comment: Then I'd use one collection for everything... You might have some problems using autoforms though, but using a rigid schema for all "shared" properties plus one schemaless object would work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally come up with a completely different approach.

I've created a server publication that returns the list of items ids and types to be displayed. The client can then fetch these from the relevant collections.

This allows me to maintain separate collections for each type, thus avoiding issues related to trying to maintain a Master collection type. Our data-model integrity is preserved.

At the same time I don't have to over-publish the data to the client. The workload on the server to calculate the ID list is minimal, and outweighs the disadvantages of the other two approaches by quite a long way in my opinion.

The basic publication looks like this (in Coffeescript):

```
Meteor.publish 'timeline', (options, limit) ->

   check options, Object
   check limit, Match.Optional Number

   sub = this

   limit = Math.min limit ? 10, 200

   # We use the peerlibrary:reactive-mongo to enable meteor reactivity on the server

   @ids = {}
   tracker = Tracker.autorun =>

      # Run a find operation on the collections that can be displayed in the timeline,
      # and add the ids to an array

      collections = ['A', 'B']

      items = []
      for collectionName in collections
         collection = Mongo.Collection.get collectionName
         collection.find({}, { fields: { updatedOn: 1 }, limit: limit, sort: { updatedOn: -1 }}).forEach (item) ->
            item.collection = collectionName
            items.push item

      # Sort the array and crop it to the required length

      items = items.sort (a,b) -> new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)
      items = items[0...limit]
      newIds = {}

      # Add/Remove the ids from the 'timeline' collection

      for doc in items

         id = doc._id
         newIds[id] = true

         # Add this id to the publication if we didn't have it before

         if not @ids[id]?
            @ids[id] = moment doc.updatedOn
            sub.added 'timeline', id, { collection: doc.collection, docId: id, updatedOn: doc.updatedOn }

         # If the update time has changed then it needs republishing

         else if not moment(doc.updatedOn).isSame @ids[id]
            @ids[id] = doc.updatedOn
            sub.changed 'timeline', id, { collection: doc.collection, docId: id, updatedOn: doc.updatedOn }

      # Check for items that are no longer in the result

      for id of @ids
         if not newIds[id]?
            sub.removed 'timeline', id
            delete @ids[id]

   sub.onStop ->
      tracker.stop()

   sub.ready()
```

Note that I'm using peerlibrary:reactive-publish for the server-side autorun.
The queries fetch just the latest ids from each collection, then it places them into a single array, sorts them by date and crops the array length to the current limit.

The resulting ids are then added to the `timeline` collection, which provides for a reactive solution on the client.

On the client it's a simply a matter of subscripting to this collection, then subscribing the individual item subscriptions themselves. Something like this:

```
Template.timelinePage.onCreated ->

   @autorun =>

      @limit = parseInt(Router.current().params['limit']) || 10

      sub = @subscribe 'timeline', {}, @limit
      if sub.ready()

         items = Timeline.find().fetch()

         As = _.pluck _.where(items, { collection: 'a' }), 'docId'
         @aSub = @subscribe 'a', { _id: { $in: As }}

         Bs = _.pluck _.where(items, { collection: 'b' }), 'docId'
         @bSub = @subscribe 'b', { _id: { $in: Bs }}
```

Finally, the template can iterate one the timeline subscription and display the appropriate item based on its type.